# Passing Java Object to Angular for specific requirement

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I am developing an application with Angular and Spring Boot. I have a model **User** which contains for example 10 fields. For a specific need, the frontend app needs just 3 or 4 fields(for example firstName, lastName, position and email).

**In this case, what is the best method should I follow ? (Performances)**

1- I create another class which contains 4 fields and use it to send the users list.

2- I send all users with 10 fields ?

If there is another way or method, please share it.

Answer (score 1):

GrpahQL is a technology built to solve that problem. As a best practice is always good to send from the server only what you need.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue , what i have done is :

- **in the backend** : sending an `User` object User in which i fill just the 4 fields which i need in the front (fill the other fields with a `null` value).
- in the **frontend** : my `User` model contains just the 4 fields
- after getting the object from the backend a simple assignment is sufficient to fill you object.

**advantge** : minimize the size of sent data via network.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: So you suggest to send all fields (4 with data and the other 6 fields with null). I think with this way, we don't minimize 100% nah ?

Comment: Yes not 100% but you minimize with a big pourcentage, this is a useful solution than creating another class then move from `User` to `NewUser` (with 4 fields..) .. , if you use my solution you can see the difference in your service rest's netwotk consomation..